# SQL LEFT JOIN only newest right column entry?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two tables like this:

```
create table A
{
    id int;
    ...
}

create table B
{
    id int;
    a_id int;
    t timestamp;
    ...
}
```

A is one-to-many with B

I want to:

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id ???
```

But I want to return exactly one row for each entry in A which has the B with the newest t field (or null for Bs fields if it has no B entry).

That is rather than returning all A-B pairs, I want to only select the newest one with respect to A (or A-null if no B entry).

Is there some way to express this in SQL?  (I'm using MySQL 5.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` is *only* concerned with ensuring every row in `A` is returned, even if there is no corresponding joined row in `B`.

The need for `just one row` needs another condition.  MySQL is limitted in its options, but one could be:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  A
LEFT JOIN
  B
    ON  B.id = A.id
    AND B.t = (SELECT MAX(lookup.t) FROM B AS lookup WHERE lookup.id = A.id)
```

Another could be...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  A
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT id, MAX(t) AS t FROM B GROUP BY id
)
  AS lookup
    ON lookup.id = A.id
LEFT JOIN
  B
    ON  B.id = lookup.id
    AND B.t  = lookup.t
```

Comment: Is one more efficient than the other?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling - It depends on the data, indexes and most-of-all the RDBMS.  I don't use MySQL myself, but my understanding is that the latter will most likely generate a better plan.  The best option is to try them both and see.  Ideally with real data.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM 
    A
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT B.a_id, MAX(t) as t FROM B GROUP BY B.a_id) BMax
    ON A.id = BMax.a_id
    JOIN B
    ON B.a_id = BMax.a_id AND B.t = BMax.t
```

Answer (score 2):

you first need to get the newest `t` from `tableB` in a subquery, then join it with tableA and tableB.

```
SELECT  a.*, c.*
FROM    tableA a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT a_ID, max(t) maxT
            FROM tableB
            GROUP BY a_ID
        ) b on a.a_id = b.a_ID
        LEFT JOIN tableB c
            ON b.a_ID = c.a_ID AND
                b.maxT = c.t
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA A LEFT JOIN 
     (select a_id ,max(t) as max_t
      from tableB
      group by a_id )b
on  A.id = b.a_id
and A.t=b.max_t
```